# Is there a way to pause all Threading.Timer timers?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, timer

I am new to C# and I am working on a program that require several timers.

I was wondering if there was a way to pause all the timers simultaneously in a program when that program is running CPU intensive code?

At the moment, timers that are currently enabled tries to catch up with all the timer events that were raised during the intensive operation.

Comment: I'd strongly suggest writing a proxy class which wraps a timer and internally has a single tick event (which doesn't stop) but publishes its own Tick event, maintaining a list of subscribers to publish ticks to. Then you could add the ability to suspend/resume updates on the external event handler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you can create the list of these timers (when you are activating them) and disable these timers manually (using the [Timer.Change](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.change.aspx) method).

Answer (score 1):

You will need to keep track of all the timers you create in a list and call the change method when you do not want them to run.

```
  List<System.Threading.Timer> TimerList = new List<System.Threading.Timer>();

  Timer stateTimer = new Timer(tcb, autoEvent, 1000, 250);
  Timer responseTimer = new Timer(tcb, autoEvent, 1000, 250);  

  TimerList.add(stateTimer);
  TimerList.add(responseTimer);

foreach (System.Threading.Timer t in TimerList)
{
  T.Change(TimeSpan(0), new(TimeSpan(0));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way in the .NET framework to get a list of all running Threading.Timer instances. But you can create your own Timer wrapper that adds all running timers to a list and of course removes them when the timer finishes.

If you only want to make sure that your methods only execute when the CPU is idleing, you can set the timer's thread priority to a lower value.